# how can I create vi for creating star pattern programs in labview which we can do in c language?

Tags: vi, labview

I have this type of logic in my vi, but I don't know how to print star pattern from that condition.[image]

Comment: Use a shift register in each loop and initialise it with an empty string outside the outer loop. Replace the calculations and comparisons with equivalent LabVIEW functions from the Programming>Numeric, Comparison and Boolean palettes and use the result to select the appropriate string and append it to the shift register contents.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a lot like homework and I would suggest looking more online, but to help you get started this is how you can do it. The Formula node does not support complex type so string creation needs to be done outside the loop. The *.png is a code snippet which you should be able to import directly into LabView.

[Labview Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDHQF.png)